# What was the stand of K Kamaraj about anti-Hindi agitation of 1965?

Tags: india, language, political-history

What was the stand of [K Kamaraj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K._Kamaraj) in [anti Hindi agitation in 1965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Hindi_agitations_of_Tamil_Nadu)? 
What were his actions to stop the people from riot?
And whether the leaders from Congress in Tamilnadu supported the Hindi imposition?

Comment: I have added links and edited the title, I hope that is fine. Also, you're asking 2-3 different questions here, so it is better to ask them separately.

Comment: @taninamdar Looks like you totally changed the whole thing.

Comment: @PraveenKumar My bad, I've edited the title again.